# Is it possible to export Leads and Sales Processes

Tags: sales-process

is it possible to export the lead and sales processes in workbench? I would  like to load the data in another org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export lead using data Loader and migrate it , but in case of sales process: -
You will have to create your sales processes in the target org. Usually, a sales process would be associated with an opportunity record type. After manually creating your sales processes, you can deploy the changeset with the associated record type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!, becausw what i want is to copy from sales and lead process from org1 to org 2 so I just want to export from org 1 and import it to org 2 using data loader without manually creating lead and sales process

Comment: for lead it is possible but in case of sales process you need to create it manually

Comment: if the answer helps you then  accept the answer so that other can find it useful.